# create Edges and Vertex from same csv file in datastax graph

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am working on loading csv file from dataloader in datastax graph.

My csv files structure is following

first file(Year_2015.txt)

YearID

second file(BaseVehicle_2005.txt)

BaseVehicleID|YearID|MakeID|ModelID

for first file I have create vertex level as year and key as YearID for second I have create vertex level as BaseVehicle while key as BaseVehicleID and ignore YearID,MakeID,ModelID. Now I want to create edge between second(BaseVehicle) and first(Year) with edge level year and property YearID but nothing has work for me. Please let me know what i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has examples : https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglCSV.html

Below is a sample loader script that works on JSON data, but it shows how to load both Vertices and Edges from the same record, using mappers to decide which elements to use.

---

```
config load_threads: 8
config batch_size: 1000
config load_new: true
config driver_retry_attempts: 10
config driver_retry_delay: 1000

/** SAMPLE INPUT
  {"actor_name":"'Bear'Boyd, Steven","title_name":"The Replacements","year":"2000","role":"Defensive Tackle - Washington Sentinels","episode":"The Replacements"}
 */
input = File.json(filename )

//Defines the mapping from input record to graph elements
actorMapper = {
    key "actor_name"           // the unique id for an actor
    label "actor"
    ignore "title_name"
    ignore "role"
    ignore "year"
    ignore "episode"
}

titleMapper = {
    key "title_name"           // the unique id for a title
    label "title"
    ignore "sex"
    ignore "actor_name"
    ignore "role"
    ignore "episode"
}

castMapper = {
    label "cast"
    outV "actor_name", {
        label "actor"
        key "actor_name"
    }
    inV "title_name", {
        label "title"
        key "title_name"
    }
    ignore "year"
    ignore "sex"
    // remaining should be edge properties
    // pickup role as property
    // pickup episode as property
}

//Load vertex records from the input according to the mapping
load(input).asVertices(actorMapper)
load(input).asVertices(titleMapper)
load(input).asEdges(castMapper)
```